# Using persistent storage in linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, crash-reports

I am trying to use persistent store(Pstore) available in linux kernel but somehow I am not getting the logs in case of kernel panics. I made the following kernel modules in kernel config file as built in:

```
CONFIG_PSTORE=y 
CONFIG_PSTORE_CONSOLE=y 
CONFIG_PSTORE_RAM=y
```

Now a/c to documentation [pstore](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/pstore) I should get the logs on next reboot in /sys/fs/pstore/... (or /dev/pstore/...) but couldn't find the logs there.
Am I missing something...?

Comment: Check kernel log using `$ dmesg` and see if any platform device is registered with this driver.

Comment: i could not find any thing named pstore/persistant store driver in the boot log ,could you plz mention which driver specific to pstore i should look for....? thanks...

Answer (score 4):

Besides the kernel config options:

```
CONFIG_PSTORE=y
CONFIG_PSTORE_CONSOLE=y
CONFIG_PSTORE_PMSG=y
CONFIG_PSTORE_RAM=y
```

I had to reserve a part of memory in which the logs will be saved. I did this through the device tree like this:

```
reserved-memory {
    #address-cells = <2>;
    #size-cells = <2>;
    ranges;

    pstore: pstore@FF00000 {
        no-map;
        reg = <0x0 0xFF00000 0x0 0x00100000>;  /* pstore/ramoops buffer
            starts at memory address 0xFF00000 and is of size 0x00100000 */
    };
};

ramoops {
    compatible = "ramoops";
    memory-region = <&pstore>;
    record-size     = <0x0 0x00020000>;
    console-size    = <0x0 0x00020000>;
    pmsg-size       = <0x0 0x00020000>;
};
```

Also, check if the following kernel patch is present (which is needed for the kernel to be able to parse the options given above):
https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/kernel/common/+/195160/

Another way is to turn it on through the kernel cmdline, for example:

```
ramoops.mem_address=0x30000000 ramoops.mem_size=0x100000 memmap=0x100000$0x30000000
```

Answer (score 3):

check if below config options are enabled

```
CONFIG_PSTORE=y
CONFIG_PSTORE_CONSOLE=y
**CONFIG_PSTORE_FTRACE=y**
CONFIG_PSTORE_RAM=y
```

But why /dev/pstore file?, it's not needed,

To check if console-ramoops working, 
do echo Trigger a kernel panic using command

`echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger`

then reboot device manually. after system boots up, run command "/sys/fs/pstore/console-ramoops", check if console_ramoops has got anything logged.

Comment: thank you, I have included the missing config ,but still cant see any logs in /sys/fs/pstore/ ..... ny leads why this is happening.... and i dont have device file for pstore i.e; "/dev/pstore doesn't exist"

Comment: thank you , i tried the above mentioned step i don't have "console_ramoops" inside /sys/fs/pstore folder.... ,Apart from these steps are any other changes required in kernel in order to make pstore working..... ?

Comment: Hi there, just wondering have you solved this? I have the same issue, all the needed options are turned on, but there is no /sys/fs/pstore/console-ramoops.

Comment: same for me. No way to get ramoops log. and ramoops documentation in kernel tree is not up to date..

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare platform data as described by @[shadowfire](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3566346/shadowfire). But all kernel cannot use device tree for ramoops.

Generic way to do it, is to add in the source file for your hardware (example for mx6ul : **arch/arm/mach-imx/mach-imx6ul.c**) the following piece of code in the function xxx_init_machine :

```
#include <linux/pstore_ram.h>
[...]

static struct ramoops_platform_data ramoops_data = {
        .mem_size               = <...>,
        .mem_address            = <...>,
        .mem_type               = <...>,
        .record_size            = <...>,
        .dump_oops              = <...>,
        .ecc                    = <...>,
};

static struct platform_device ramoops_dev = {
        .name = "ramoops",
        .dev = {
                .platform_data = &ramoops_data,
        },
};

[... inside xxx_init_machine ...]
int ret;

ret = platform_device_register(&ramoops_dev);
if (ret) {
    printk(KERN_ERR "unable to register platform device\n");
    return ret;
}
```

More info available in documentation : [ramoops](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.2/source/Documentation/ramoops.txt)

Do you have logs in dmesg which can confirm that ramoops is enabled successfully ?

```
# dmesg | grep -i "pstore\|ramoops"
console [pstore-1] enabled
pstore: Registered ramoops as persistent store backend
ramoops: attached 0x20000@0x80000000, ecc: 0/0
```

Moreover you must mount pstore directory, that's why the directory is empty on your rootfs :

```
mount -t pstore -o kmsg_bytes=8000 - /sys/fs/pstore
```

Default size for the mount is 10 Kbytes in you don't set the kmsg_bytes option. You can use /etc/fstab to mount it automatically.